# Python struct.unpack in delphi

Tags: python, delphi, binary

How to use built in python function named: [`struct.unpack`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) in delphi just like what python do.
here is an example:

```
x = struct.unpack(">H",data[offset:offset+2])[0]
```

Comment: Not that it matters to your question, but `(x,) = unpack_from(">H", data, offset)` is a bit more concise and avoid the magic number 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>H` is a big endian unsigned two byte value.

In Delphi you would do this:

```
var
  x: Word;
  data: TBytes;
....
x := ntohs(PWord(@data[offset])^);
```

Let's look at this in more detail:

- `data` is an array of bytes and so `data[offset]` is the value you are trying to unpack.
- `ntohs` converts from network byte order (big endian) to host byte order.
- Since the parameter of `ntohs` is a `Word`, we need to treat `data[offset]` as a word and hence the cast.

In order to call `ntohs` you'll need to use the `Winsock` unit.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not on the platforms that Delphi code traditionally executes (x86/x64). I think it could be an issue on ARM, but that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: but there is no information about fields and type of them in my binary file, is there any solution for this ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean